# On the circuit level, how does a graphics card, GPU, or other pixel plotting hardware to a display work?

Tags: voltage

I am thinking here on terms of electrons, electrical components, and silicon; nothing above that. Is the internal structure of a GPU similar to that of a CPU, i.e., registers to hold data, caches to hold temporary copies of data to reduce access time, etc.

All in all, what does the body of a graphics rendering device/hardware under any magnitude of difficulty from the most simple graphics rendering hardware available.

Example of a simple graphics circuit: Sega Genesis's Yamaha YM7101.

I could certainly study its specs, but the circuit level details are hidden, undocumented, or not shone on enough for me to disassemble it or get a better understanding of it.

I suppose the will write, on an x86 example, two bytes through the bus to the card, which will intercept and carry those bytes in to registers, which will then do some other extra circuitry level details I'm unaware of to get it to a display's screen.

Any further delving details I should know, or you can clarify for me?

Answer (score 2):

A graphics card, at it's core, is a [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) and a [RAMDAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAMDAC). Now that DVI is probably more common than VGA, the RAMDAC isn't strictly a "digital to analog" converter, but anyhow, it is circuitry to take what's in the framebuffer and convert it to whatever electrical signals are required by the monitor interface.

The GPU is very similar to a CPU, except it is heavily optimized for graphics calculation. It accepts commands to perform 3D transformations, apply textures, lighting, and whatever else, using the [video ram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_memory)<sup>1</sup> as working space, and ultimately putting the result in the framebuffer, which may be a designated region in the video RAM.

The instruction set used by the GPU is probably proprietary, since in most cases it is the competitive intellectual property of companies like [NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/) and [ATI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATI_Technologies) (now [AMD](http://www.amd.com/)). The public interface to the GPU is defined by software APIs like [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) and [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), so the GPU manufacturers, who also develop the drivers and libraries that translate these software APIs to communications with the GPU, are free to change the implementation of their GPUs.

<sup>1: there have been very cheap video cards integrated into the motherboard that use a dedicated chunk of ordinary RAM. This is terrible for performance, but does serve to demonstrate that video RAM is really just more RAM, on the graphics card. There are also [CPUs with GPU functionality integrated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Fusion).</sup>